# How to get sentences from pastebin.com and put them into a list?

Tags: python

So I have this pastebin link here: https://pastebin.com/raw/egumzQZD
And I want a way for python to get the sentences in the pastebin link and put it in a list. Is there any way to do this? So for example:

```py
list = [
'This is a sentence.',
'This is another sentence.',
'Oh look! Here\'s another sentence!',
'My... my... Another one.',
'Dear god.... -sigh- here\'s another one.',
'I might stop here.'
]
```

My goal is so that the python code can print a random sentence using:

```
print(random.choice(list))
```

Comment: Web scraping. Scrape from the URL using modules like BeautifulSoup, etc. Then pass it into the list.

What efforts have you put onto this?

Comment: Just download and split the data. Did you check out the [inbuilt request support](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request)? Do you know how to split the raw data?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to do [web **scraping**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/web-scraping/info) here. A sample example using `requests` module

```
import requests
data = requests.get("https://pastebin.com/raw/egumzQZD")
new_list = data.text.split("\r\n")

print(new_list)
```

output

```
['This is a sentence.', 'This is another sentence.', "Oh look! Here's another sentence!", 'My... my... Another one.', "Dear god.... -sigh- here's another one.", 'I might stop here.']
```

Comment: @ProfessorPuddle if it works, then you can accept and upvote the solution.

Comment: sorry i'm new to stack hehe. it says i need 15 reputation or something. what does that mean?

Comment: @ProfessorPuddle it mean you need 15 points (see top right corner with your profile image) to upvote an answer

Comment: Aah. Ok. Thank you.